# Firebase database structure with 2 collections

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-structures, nosql

I am new to Firebase and would like to receive feedback on my proposed database structure. I am building a mobile app using 1) Firebase to store my user data, and 2) an external API to fetch recipe data.

I am wondering if my approach below would be acceptable for building a basic app?

Here is my database structure:

```
 Users Collection
   user1: {
    --name: "John"
    --recentlyViewed: {key1: '0001',key2: '0002',...key25: '0025'} // max 25 elements
    --favorited: {key1: '0001', key2: '0002',...key1000: '1000'} // no max number of elements
    },
    user2: {...},

Recipe Thumbnails Collection
   '0001': {  // this key (or ID number) can be used in the GET request to the external API for more data on the item
    --title: "Curry"
    --description: "Stew"
    --image: "www.url.com"
   },
   '0002': {
    --title: "Fish"
    --description: "Stew"
    --image: "www.url.com"
   },
```

Here is my approach:

My app shows each user their "Recently Viewed" and "Favorited" recipes as thumbnails. In order to retrieve the data for each thumbnail, I am making a GET request to the external API.

For each GET request, the API returns a ton of information (approx. 200 data points), however I only need to access 3 data points -- title, description, and image URL. Therefore, I thought it would be more efficient if *every time the user views a recipe,* to save the necessary thumbnail information (title, description, and URL) as a document in a Firebase collection, with a key of the unique ID that corresponds to the external API.

If a user taps on a thumbnail, I would make a GET request to the external API (using the unique record number, which is saved as the Key for each document) to access additional information about the recipe and display it on a new screen to the user.

Comment: How frequently do recipes change? Right now you're guaranteed to do n+1 reads where n is the number of recipes the user has viewed or favorited. If the recipes don't change often you could denormalize further, copying the data into the users favorites and get them all in a single read. The downside here is that a recipe update now requires some `m` updates, where `m` is the number of users with the recipe favorited/recently-viewed. Using firestore you could query the data based on if the user has favorited it.

Comment: @Chris Thanks very much for your response! The recipes never change. To clarify, when you say "copying the data into the users favorites and get them all in a single read", do you mean saving the Recipe data directly to the User -- and therefore getting rid of the entire Recipe Thumbnail collection? If so, wouldn't this be inefficient, if there are approx 500K - 1M recipe records total, and multiple users would be saving the same information?

Comment: Correct, you lose storage efficiency and gain read efficiency. That's the tradeoff you can make - you go from reading the User one time and having necessary information, to reading user and then having to make some n reads, one for each favorite and recently-viewed recipe. The downside is you have redundancy in storage and challenges keeping the data consistent. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/denormalization-in-databases/

Comment: @Chris Denormalization is a new concept to me, this is so helpful for understanding and planning my db structure. Thanks for pointing me in this direction, so helpful, greatly appreciate it!

Comment: You can use DTOs when getting data from the external API and then create another class with only the needed fields, that should be used to write data to Firebase.